# Trigger code error

Tags: apex, code, after-trigger, compile-error

I am really new to triggers and not sure how I fix this error, please help.

[image]

Thank You,
Lorr

Answer (score 1):

Add a space after the keyword "on".

```
trigger SAR_FORM on SAR_FORM__c (after update) {
```

Probably also worth doing [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro).

Comment: Thank you, I will def do this trailhead.